# Find all documents where a particular field of all elements of a subcollection are included inside a given array in MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Working with MongoDB and Mongoose, let's say ,for example, that I have this schema:

```
var componentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name             : String,
price            : Number
});

var partSchema = mongoose.Schema({
componentId        : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Component' },
quantity           : Number
});

var robotSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name             : String,
type             : Number,
parts            : [partSchema]
});
```

Every robot needs a set of components to be build.

Since a robot may need more than a single copy of a component (e.g. 10 bolts, 5 screws, 1 transistor...), we store inside the robot model an array of **parts**, where *each part contain the reference to a component plus an additional field*, quantity.

Now I'm interested in finding, given an array of **component**'s names (or, eventually, given an array of componentIds) all the robots that I can build with those types of components (notice that a component doesn't include quantity, I just assume that I have an infinite amount of those component), ordered by the one that uses most components of the given array.

```
Robot A: 2 bolts, 2 transistors 
Robot B: 10 bolts, 2 capacitors, 3 bars of plutonium  
Robot C: 5 bolts, 1 capacitor, 5 transistors

I have [bolts, capacitors, transistors]. 
Query results:  

    Robot C  
    Robot A 

(In this order!)
```

Is it even possibile with a complex MongoDB query?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You want to find robot documents such that, for each component in your component list, the quantity for that component in the info is less than the quantity listed in the robot document, and that your component list exhausts the component list of the robot.

```
// robot docs
{
    "name" : "My Fun Robot v3",
    "type" : 999,
    "parts" : [
        { "_id" : 0, "quantity" : 2 },
        { "_id" : 1, "quantity" : 5 },
        { "_id" : 2, "quantity" : 1 },
        { "_id" : 3, "quantity" : 7 }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "My Pun Robot v1",
    "type" : 222,
    "parts" : [
        { "_id" : 4, "quantity" : 3 },
        { "_id" : 1, "quantity" : 4 },
        { "_id" : 2, "quantity" : 8 },
        { "_id" : 6, "quantity" : 1 }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "My Sun Robot v876",
    "type" : 9834,
    "parts" : [
        { "_id" : 0, "quantity" : 6 },
        { "_id" : 1, "quantity" : 400 },
        { "_id" : 2, "quantity" : 800 },
        { "_id" : 3, "quantity" : 1000 }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "My Gun Robot v0",
    "type" : 1337,
    "parts" : [
        { "_id" : 0, "quantity" : 1 },
        { "_id" : 1, "quantity" : 1 },
        { "_id" : 2, "quantity" : 1 },
    ]
}
```

and component info

```
\\ component info
var components = [
    { "_id" : 0, "quantity" : 20 },
    { "_id" : 1, "quantity" : 20 },
    { "_id" : 2, "quantity" : 20 },
    { "_id" : 3, "quantity" : 20 },
    { "_id" : 4, "quantity" : 20 }
]
```

Construction of the query:

```
// for each component, we either need the component not to be required for the robot, or for the robot's quantity required to be less than the quantity we have
var query = {}
var comp_cond = []
components.forEach(function(comp) {
    comp_cond.push({ "$or" : [{ "parts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "_id" : comp._id, "quantity" : { "$lte" : comp.quantity } } } }, { "parts._id" : { "$ne" : comp._id } } ]})
})
query["$and"] = comp_cond
// we need to make sure that there's no part in `parts` that's not in the components array
query["parts"] = { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "_id" : { "$nin" : components.map(function(comp) { return comp._id }) } } } }
```

I won't show the actual query for the above example because it's really long. You can run the code in the mongo shell and see it.

```
> db.robots.find(query, { "_id" : 0, "name" : 1 })
{ "name" : "My Fun Robot v3" }
{ "name" : "My Gun Robot v0" }
```

I believe this is the correct result. You should do more exhaustive testing to make sure it handles all the ways a component list can fail to match a robots parts list.

Comment: Many thanks for this GREAT answer, I'm making some test and I'll update here as soon as I have some tangible result.